# Проверка авторизации через FB (JS SDK) на серверной стороне

Tags: facebook-api, oauth2, facebooksdk

После вызова FB.login я получаю в ответ следующие поля:

- accessToken
- expiresIn
- signedRequest
- userID

для VK есть документация как проверить авторизацию на сервере

[Авторизация на удаленной стороне](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_2?f=6.1.+VK.Observer.subscribe)

Можно ли так же сделать и для FB?

Answer (score 0):

Для facebook реализована своя логика декодирования и проверки

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr

алгоритм:

1. Split the signed request into two parts delineated by a '.'
   character    (eg. 238fsdfsd.oijdoifjsidf899)
2. Decode the first part - the encoded signature - from base64url
3. Decode the second part - the payload - from base64url and then
   decode the resultant JSON object

Код на php:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  $secret = "appsecret"; // Use your app secret here

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  // confirm the signature
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/178372)

Comment: @cheops ок, понял!